# Are there any PHP CQL drivers/clients available

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

Are there any php extensions for cassandra yet like the php_mysql extension, or are there any PHP wrappers available. 
I have seen phpCassa and similar ones but it doesnt quite have the same flexibility as the CQL (plus i hear it may be faster to use CQL, not sure why...)

See [CQL](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/cql/CQL.textile)!

Answer (score 4):

There's a [PDO CQL driver](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/), which seems like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: yea i saw that page but theres nothing to download there, just points to the php.net page describing PDO

Comment: Looks like you have to check out the source from git - http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/source/browse/README.md - no download package yet.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Using+Cassandra+with+PHP

Have you read this yet?  Seems like it gives you a few options to interact with Cassandra directly from PHP

Here is an example of the code you could use in PHP.  Seems SQL-esque enough to me:

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples#PHP

Answer (score 1):

Check out evseevnn's php-cassandra-binary: https://github.com/evseevnn/php-cassandra-binary

It uses Cassandra's binary protocol (no thrift) so it can be installed without any extensions!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you as well

http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/search/label/cassandra

Part 1 explains how to use PHPCassa to connect to Cassandra and fetch data via CQL

This is using PHPCassa

Regards,
Tamil